# Quote argument strings Shell

Tags: linux, shell

Can I quote arguments that have spaces or special chars in the command line? If not, how is this handled. We have one argument that is a multiword string. I'm sure this has been asked many times, but I cant find it.

```
./myscript name=bob occupation=guy who does stuff
```

Comment: As a matter of fact you must quote arguments with spaces and other special characters

Comment: Have you tried writing `./myscript name=bob occupation="guy who does stuff"`?

Comment: Or, you could try `./myscript 'name=bob' 'occupation=guy who does stuff'`, or `./myscript na'me'="bo"b occupation=guy\ who\ does\ stuff`.  There are many ways to quote a string.

Comment: There is no one place you can quote arguments to make it Just Work. In addition to quoting when running it, the script needs to be carefully (re)written to handle special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use quotes. Something like:

```
$ var='abc def'
$ echo "$var"
abc def
```

You can read more [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters).

Your case example (note I'm calling the script that needs the multiword string from the another script in this example):

```
sh ./test.sh 'this is a test'
```

test.sh contains `echo $1` and prints `this is a test`. Hope this solution works.

Comment: Why not demonstrate with the material from the question?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Though it would be clear enough. I've added an example of script being called with such argument.